# include part of a website in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to include part of another website in my website.

can i do this - im thinking may use an iframe but how can i make it only show say one  on the other site.

for example, if the other site has:

```
<div id="a_div">
content here
</div>

<div id="b_div">
other content here
</div>
```

how can i include only the *a_div* div on my site so only:

```
content here
```

will display?

Comment: You can't do it with an iframe. Only option would be to screen scrape with code on your server and display it that way.

Comment: @Farax, and I see you did not read it, it is another domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you're trying to do, sorry, It's not possible to filter the iframe content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe tag` and append id of div with `#` in url:

```
<iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com/page.html#a_div"></iframe>
```

It would focus the particular section but it is not possible to filter the content only if site you are showing in iframe allows you to get that specific part.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there is no way to filter the iframe content.

For security reasons it also isn't possible to read the contents of the iframe and then filter it to only show the section you want.

In order to achieve this you need to create a server side script that scrapes the other website and returns what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to filter the content of your frame.

But it's possible to use curl php method to get a part of your website and modify like you want with parsing method.

http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Answer (score 0):

if the website you are trying to display in the iframe is on the same domain as yours you can filter out just a section you need...else you can't access data cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you have access to the server the other website in question is running on. Then you could enable cross-origin resource sharing ([cors](http://enable-cors.org/index.html)).

After that you can just use `jQuery.load` or any other ajax request.

Otherwise it isn't possible (cross domain policy) as mentioned a couple of times already.